# Magento Customer Module Override is not working

Tags: php, magento

I just want to Override the magento custom account

my folder structure is like

```
local
  Practise
    Coreextended
      controllers
        Frontend
          Customer
            AccountController.php
      etc
        config.xml
```

And my

AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountControllerq.php';
    //we need to add this one since Magento wont recognize it automatically  
    class Practise_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer_AccountControllerextends Mage_Customer_AccountController
    {//here, you extended the core controller with our

        public function indexAction()
        { die('Here1');
        parent::indexAction();
        //you can always use default functionality
        }

        public function myactionAction()
        {
        die('Here2');
        //my code
        //you can write your own methods / actions
        }

        public function mymethod()
        {
        die('Here3');
        //my code
        //you can write your own methods
        }

        public function loginAction()
        {die('Here4');
        //finally you can write your code that will rewrite the whole core method
        //and you can call for your own methods, as you have full control over core controller
        }
    }
```

config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <practise_coreextended>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
        </practise_coreextended>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <practise_coreextended before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">
                            Practise_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer
                        </practise_coreextended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

and one more file in `app\etc\modules\Practise_Coreextended.xml`

The new module is showing in the admin configuration settings. But when i tried to navigate the login page none of the die is printing.It is still showing the normal page.
Is i miss anything...

Comment: what is it AccountControllerq.php ?. Check this name.

Comment: it was  AccountController.php. for debugging i changed the name.

Comment: Where is your rewrite class ? That should be mentioned in your config.xml

Answer (score 2):

Finally your config.xml should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Practise_Coreextended>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Practise_Coreextended>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <coreextended>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Practise_Coreextended</module>
            <frontName>coreextended</frontName>
          </args>
      </coreextended>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>

        <rewrite>        
            <practise_coreextended_customer_accountcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_Customer_AccountController  -->
                <to>/coreextended/customer_account/</to> <!-- Practise_Coreextended_Customer_AccountController  -->
            </practise_coreextended_customer_accountcontroller>
        </rewrite>

  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <coreextended>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Practise_Coreextended</module>
          <frontName>admin_coreextended</frontName>
        </args>
      </coreextended>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

And check your include path of controller or use below one,'

```
<?php
require_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";  
class Practise_Coreextended_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

}
```

**Update:**

And your Practise_Coreextended.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Practise_Coreextended>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Practise_Coreextended>
  </modules>
</config>
```

And you already tried to install this module (may be) with different version. It's better to clear registry (module's entry) in `core_resource` table. Just open this table and delete if any entries regarding to this module.

And finally remove cache in `var/cache`/ and if you using Enterprise Edition  then clear `var/full_page_cache/`. That's it.

Comment: But it should be. Actually I gotta go. surely I ll check it later. I'm sorry.

Comment: Check module version in app/etc/modules/Practise_Coreextended.xml and your config.xml file. It should be same.

Comment: I could not find any version tag in Practise_Coreextended.xml file. Am i missing something..